# Need a formula that will only show the characters in a cell up to the first number in the cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I want to shorten postcode information in a cell to only show the first or first and second letter. i.e. WF17 would show WF only or S17 would only show S.
The range of cells will have a mix of 1 character and 2 character postcodes so I would need the formula to cover both scenarios.

Comment: What have you already tried? We help with specific problems, but we are not a code-writing site.

Answer (score 0):

I found a not so elegant solution.

So, if you have A1,A2 etc filled with codes that start with either 1 letter or 2 letters in another column, do the following.
In B1 type

`=VALUE(MID(A1,2,1))`

Use autofill for the rest of the cells in B and you should have either a number or an error.
Now in C1 type

`=IF(ISERROR(B1),LEFT(A1,2),LEFT(A1,1))`

Autofilling the rest of C should give you what you needed :)

Comment: `=IF(ISERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,2,1))),LEFT(A1,2),LEFT(A1,1))`

Comment: yeah, combined :)
I still do the recursive thing of problem solving, divide and conquer.

Comment: Big thank you to H, this formula, =IF(ISERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,2,1))),LEFT(A1,2),LEFT(A1,1)), worked perfectly, much appreciate.